# Sketchup wall thickness

Tags: printing, 3d, sketchup

I have this figure and I need to set the walls thickness. I need this for 3D printer.

I tried to use the Push/Pull tool but I can't use this for rounded corners.

How can I do in my case ?

[image: Sketchup project]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to do a script in Ruby, this is really a SuperUser question.

But anyway you may be looking for *Joint Push-Pull*: http://www.cad-addict.com/2008/06/sketchup-plugings-joint-push-pull-and.html.

An alternative, Smart Push-Pull: http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23341. Last time I used this (a while ago) it didn't support smoothed surfaces; if that's still the case then un-smooth it first and re-apply smoothing after extruding.

GLHF